# Django url not being found

Tags: django, url

I have just created a new Django view. I have added the path to `urls.py` in amongst my other working urls:

```
url(r'^events/new/$', 'crewcal.views.new_event', name='new_event'),
url(r'^commit/$', 'crewcal.views.commit'),
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', profile, name='profile'),
```

The others work fine. I have restarted the server and tried to make the request, but I am getting this error. Can anyone help?

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/commit
Using the URLconf defined in ssc.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
^events/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$
^events/new/$ [name='new_event']
^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$ [name='profile']
^register/$ [name='join']
^login/$
^logout/$ [name='logout']
^log_in/$ [name='log_in']
^admin/
The current URL, commit, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Are you sure its saved in the right spot? I don't see the pattern listed in your error at all.

Comment: Your comment helped, I have two url.py files, one in the main project folder, the other in the app folder. Silly. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure but may be this missing slash at the end of the url causing error: Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/commit

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your .pyc files and restart the server.

```
find /path/to/project/ -name "*.pyc" -delete
```